# Problema con el diseño de un nuevo botón

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando botones desde la `Activity` y no desde el `layout`:

```
    btn0 = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    btn0.setText(lista.get(i).toString());
    btn0.setTextSize(14);
    btn0.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    btn0.setTextAppearance(ContextApp.getAppContext(), R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless_Colored);
    btn0.setAllCaps(false);

    int imgResource = R.drawable.categoria_nueva;
    btn0.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imgResource, 0, 0, 0);

    btn0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btn0.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
    ll_menu_categorias1.addView(btn0);
```

Pero cuando se crea no se posiciona de la misma manera que los botones que si tengo en mi `layout`, ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un botón de los que si tengo creado en el `layout`

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/categoria_parahoy"
                android:text="Para hoy"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece faltarle el padding, prueba a añadírselo así:

```
btn0.setPadding(15,15,15,15);
```

Las unidades no son dp, son padding-pixels, así que tendrás que acomodarlas para que se parezca o convertir los valores a dp.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias @Carmen ! con lo que comentas y además, `btn0.setCompoundDrawablePadding(35);` queda solucionado, gracias!! :)

Comment: Estupendo, no hay de que @UserNameYo